# Unable to connect AWS Client VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, ip, aws-vpn

I am getting below error while connecting to AWS Client VPN.

VPN File is correct with same file I am able to connect with other System.

Local area network IP address configuration not found. PLease contact your administrator

Any idea whats wrong with ths VM?

I tried with multiple times buts getting same issue looks like something changed related to networking or IP configuration

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm running into the same thing on Windows.